# casting error in polymorphic array sorting

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

I looked into a lots of threads but none of them discussed this problem. I have a super abstract class with 2 subclasses and I created a polymorphic array with a size of 10 and 5 objects stored in it. However, when I try to sort it, an error appear indicating this: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Sale cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable`
I had implemented the Comparable interface and the ComapreTo method correctly. I had also tried using array lists and Collections.Sort, but nothing changed. Here is my sample code:

```
public abstract class Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {

    protected String name;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Animal v1) {
        return this.name.compareTo(v1.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {

    public Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Chicken extends Animal {

    public Chicken(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal[] animalArray = new Animal[10];
        animalArray[0] = new Cat("Winstron");
        animalArray[1] = new Chicken("Hello");
        animalArray[2] = new Chicken("Manan");
        animalArray[3] = new Cat("Anything");
        animalArray[4] = new Cat("JustString");

        for (int i = 0; i < animalArray.length; i++) {
            if (animalArray[i] != null) {
                System.out.println(animalArray[i].toString());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");

    
        Arrays.sort(animalArray, 0, 5);


        for (int i = 0; i < animalArray.length; i++) {
            if (animalArray[i] != null) {
                System.out.println(animalArray[i].toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

This just a sample, and for some reason it works fine, but in my main code it just keeps telling either of my subclasses cannot be casted into comparable.

Comment: The error message mentions a class called `Sale`, but you showed `Animal`, `Cat` and `Chicken`...

Comment: Why do you post an unrelated sample code that is working fine instead of the code that has the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Sale` doesn't implement the `Comparable` interface. This means that it's not extending the class with `Comparable` and it doesn't implements the interface.

Answer (score 0):

So, I know this is confusing, but my interface was exactly like the sample provided here. Also, it turns out all I needed is to create a new project and copy my source code to it. That made my program works perfectly.